# Azure relay hybrid connection with multiple listener

Tags: azure, azure-hybrid-connections, azure-relay

If Azure relay hybrid connection has multiple listeners, will race condition raised between the listeners & eventually only one listener processes the incoming request (or) each listener will receives copy of request and process it? please clarify

Answer (score 1):

According to [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-protocol):

Listen message

To indicate readiness to the service that a listener is ready to accept connections, it creates an outbound WebSocket connection. The connection handshake carries the name of a Hybrid Connection configured on the Relay namespace, and a security token that confers the "Listen" right on that name.

When the WebSocket is accepted by the service, the registration is complete and the established WebSocket is kept alive as the "control channel" for enabling all subsequent interactions. The service allows **up to 25** concurrent listeners for one Hybrid Connection. The quota for AppHooks is to be determined.

For Hybrid Connections, if there are two or more active listeners, incoming connections are **balanced across them in random order**; fair distribution is attempted with best effort.

Comment: Thanks, though the document not providing straight forward answer I assume, it means one incoming connection is handled by, at most only one listener.